# mongoose delete files uploaded earlier

Tags: node.js, mongoose, file-upload

I am using multer to upload files from the client side using a form which works perfectly fine. I have also implemented editRouter to edit the posts content. So, if I upload a file in the edit form, that is also uploaded and the post is updated. However, the previous file remains on the server. There is a similar problem while deleting the post. How do I ensure that the previously uploaded file is also deleted in such case?

postRouter.js

```
postRouter.route('/:postId/edit')
.put(authenticate.verifyUser, upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.file)
    {
        req.body.image = req.file.filename;
    }

    Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.postId, { $set: req.body }, {new: true})
    .then((post) => {
        console.log('The post has been edited successfully');
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
        res.redirect('/post/'+post._id+'/view');
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
});

postRouter.route('/:postId/view')
.delete(authenticate.verifyUser, (req,res,next) => {
    Posts.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.postId)
    .then((resp) => {
        console.log('Post with id: '+req.params.id+' removed!');
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
        res.redirect('/');
    }, (err)=>next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
});
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) method provided by `node fs` to delete the file **BEFORE** saving the new file.

By using this approach you need to make sure you are deleting the file that you intend to delete, as a validation will go a long way.

```
fs.unlink('path/file.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('path/file.txt was deleted');
});
```

I would suggest you name your `files` based on some unique id's could be `_id` or `PostID` from mongoose, this way you are most likely to delete the correct one.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012796/7482427) if you need help as, how to rename file with multer.